# Fibered category vs indexed category

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, higher-category-theory

In Benabou's paper [Fibered categories and the foundations of naive category theory](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a7ba/3c5b0431adf514595d53ea393910c9230745.pdf), it is mentioned (end of page 31) that '*an indexed category is just a presentation of a fibered category.*'

1. It seems that Benabou argues that fibered categories formalise the same idea as indexed categories, but are better to work with. I also found very few literatures about indexed categories. So, is the conception of 'indexed category' somewhat outdated compared to 'fibered category'? (Personally, I am not an expert and temporarily I feel more comfortable with indexed categories, but now I was wondering if I should further study fibered categories for better understandings)
2. Explicitly, from [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/indexed+category), I know one can naturally obtain from an $\mathcal S$-indexed category a fibered category over $\mathcal S$, by using the Grothendieck construction. It is also claimed there that two of them are equivalent. So, conversely, how do I recover the $\mathcal S$-indexed category from this fibered category over $\mathcal S$?

Comment: The grothendieck construction is an equivalence of (2,1)-categories between fibered categories and pseudo functors out of the base. Does that answer your question? Given a fibered category, you may choose a compatible family of pushforward functors between the fibers to build the associated pseudofunctor

Comment: @DylanWilson Thank you. So, my impression is that it is something 'up to equivalence'. But, what if we begin with a 'strict' indexed category? Then, will we go back to a strict 2-functor or only a pseudo-functor up to equivalence? Maybe this is a dumb question.

Comment: “The inverse” of the Grothendieck construction is only defined up to equivalence, so I don’t think one can guarantee more than an equivalent pseudofunctor in general

Comment: N.B. The Grothendieck construction defines an equivalence of 2-categories in the strict sense, not merely a biequivalence. In particular, it is an equivalence on the underlying 1-categories.

Comment: As to the question, Bénabou's views on fibered vs indexed categories are strongly held, but they are not universal among category theorists. Since fibered categories and indexed categories are equivalent (assuming AOC), whichever structure one works with is largely a matter of preference, or of suitability to the task at hand.

Comment: One case in which the indexed viewpoint probably remains predominant is in categories indexed by a 2-category, that is, 2-functors into Cat. Fibrations of 2-categories have a relatively sparse literature, much of it quite recent, while 2-categories of 2-functors are rather well understood. These are the 2-categories Street studied in a couple of papers on 2-topoi, for instance, and are also the setting for the theory of derivators. In contrast, it is fibered, rather than indexed, $(\infty,1)$-categories that get the most attention.

Comment: @AlexanderCampbell Thank you. Good to know Grothendieck construction holds in the strict sense. By the way, what is the abbreviation AOC?

Comment: @Hang I meant the Axiom of Choice, more commonly abbreviated as AC, I suppose.

Comment: Fibred categories equipped with a [cleaving](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02XN) are equivalent to indexed categories, without Choice IIRC, and then Choice just supplies the quasi-inverse to the forgetful functor from fibred categories-with-cleaving to just fibred categories.

Comment: @KevinCarlson By categories indexed by a 2-category, do you mean strict 2-category or bicategory? Do you know the literature about this viewpoint? Thank you.

Comment: @Hang Potentially either. I think Street's work that I mentioned may still be the best reference.